# Single mysql query updating field as empty though data is showing in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, centos

**Environment:** LAMP, Mysql: 5.0, PHP: 5.1.6, CentOS

I am executing following my SQL query, updated result **some time** really strange. It is updating **box_status field empty** (`box_status` field is enum type value can be `A,L,R`). this update query running in a loop.

```
update box_master 
    set box_to_show = '0', 
        box_status = 'L' 
where box_id = '{$param_arr['box_id']}' 
and box_status in ( 'A','L')
```

I am stuck, already 2 days passed on this issue not getting any clue or solution.

code transfered from comment

**PHP**

```
$update_sql = ""; 
$update_sql = "update box_master set box_to_show = '0', box_status = 'L' where box_id = '{$param_arr['box_id']}' and box_status in ( 'A','L') "; 

$result = mysql_query ( $update_sql, $link ); 

$update_sql = ""; 

if (mysql_affected_rows ( $link ) > 0) { 
   $param_arr ['remarks'] = " box_stock is 1 or 2 and market id is not 2, so changing box to show to 0 and box_status to L from {$param_arr['box_status']}"; 
}
```

Table description

```
 desc box_master 
 Field       Type                                               Null Key    Default Extra 
 box_id      int(10) unsigned                                   NO   PRI            auto_increment 
 box_status  enum('P','D','A','L','O','N','X','I','C','S','R')  NO          MUL     P    
 box_to_show float(12,2)                                        NO          0
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with some PHP Code, if you are using any? And we need `DESC table`

Comment: Is this PHP? It's not tagged.

Comment: @tadman most of the chances are that it's PHP (but could also be python or perl) even if it wasn't tagged as such.

Comment: what's your table structure `DESCRIBE box_master;`

Comment: You need to provide some context on where you're executing this. You're also jamming in arbitrary strings into your SQL which is [never a good idea](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Are you sure this isn't being run inside a loop of your own creation by accident?

Comment: Yes it is PHP, sorry I did not add, Here is part of code:

               $update_sql = "";
               $update_sql = "update box_master set box_to_show = '0', box_status = 'L' where box_id = '{$param_arr['box_id']}' and box_status in ( 'A','L') ";
               $result = mysql_query ( $update_sql, $link );
               $update_sql = "";
               if (mysql_affected_rows ( $link ) > 0)
               {
   $param_arr ['remarks'] = " box_stock is 1 or 2 and market id is not 2, so changing box to show to 0 and box_status to L from {$param_arr['box_status']}";
               }

Comment: @tadman above code in a function

when calling it for less iteration (around 20) it is working fine. mentioned problem happening when it is in a loop and iteration is more. Also in loop few data updated correctly few not. You may noticed 'L' is hard coded, then how it is becoming empty and box_to_show is correct it is changing to 0.

Comment: @barts here is desc box_master 
Field Type Null Key Default Extra
box_id int(10) unsigned NO PRI  auto_increment
box_status enum('P','D','A','L','O','N','X','I','C','S','R') NO MUL P 
box_to_show float(12,2) NO  0